# Does async await also apply to methods called

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have the following code:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetInfo(string text)
    {
        var res = await Class.ClassMethod(text);

        if (res == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Fail");
        }
        return Ok(res);
    }
```

and this is `ClassMethod`:

```
    public async static Task<string> ClassMethod(string text)
    {
        NextClass followingClass = new NextClass();
        return followingClass.followingClassMethod(text);
    }
```

My question relates to async in the `ClassMethod`.

In this situation, `Class.ClassMethod(text)` is called with `await`, which as far as I understand, means the method will no longer be async, but will execute in order. All fine so far.

But will the await function apply to methods called within the ClassMethod function, after `await` was implemented eg will the code in `followingClassMethod` also have await applied, or will I also need to add `await` to `followingClassmethod`.

If await will apply to `followingClassMethod` will it also apply to any methods called in `followingClassMethod` and so on. If so, at what point will it stop applying?

If it does not apply, does this mean that in `ClassMethod` the constructor and the method will both be executed at the same time? Which obviously will not work. If this is the case, what can I do to resolve this, as I cannot call a constructor using async? I have seen some answers that say to wrap the constructor in a method and make that async, but that seems to me to be a bit hacky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> called with await, which as far as I understand, means the method will no longer be async, but will execute in order.

No, that's not what it means; it means that everything to the left and below (`var res =` etc) will be part of the **continuation**, and will only be executed once the awaitable thing (the result of `Class.ClassMethod(text)`) indicates completion.

However, we also need to know what `followingClassMethod` returns. It looks like it returns `string`, in which case the `async` is irrelevant, and that method always executes synchronously and simply returns an already-completed task; which means that the `var res =` continuation *also* executes immediately / synchronously. As an aside, you *probably* already get a compiler warning:

> Warning   CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

which is telling you that the `async` is not doing anything useful.

As for:

> or will I also need to add await to followingClassmethod.

You can't do that unless the result of `followingClassmethod` is itself awaitable - for example `Task<string>`; the *naive* approach there would then be to write:

```
public async static Task<string> ClassMethod(string text)
{
    NextClass followingClass = new NextClass();
    return await followingClass.followingClassMethod(text);
}
```

However this adds an unnecessary level of abstraction and gains you nothing over simply not being `async`:

```
public static Task<string> ClassMethod(string text)
{
    NextClass followingClass = new NextClass();
    return followingClass.followingClassMethod(text);
}
```

Comment: In the above case I can see that there is no need to have the ClassMethod as async. However, if it was necessary to have this as an async task, it seems you are saying that I would also have to specify await in ClassMethod otherwise it would be async?

Comment: @Alex that depends on what you think you mean by "as async". Is there actually something in here that is genuinely async? It isn't writing `async` / `await` that makes something async - that just triggers compiler magic to make it possible to write async code without going as crazy. As for your final question: no, and I explicitly gave an example where `ClassMethod` is not `async` and yet correctly passes through the awaitable nature of `followingClassMethod` (assuming that *this* is now `async`)

Comment: @MarcGravell: I think the `async`/`await` may be useful in the `ClassMethod` code. In particular, if the `NextClass` constructor threw a (non-boneheaded) exception.